# PHP Dom remove special characters

Tags: php, dom

I am trying to use PHP DOM to scrape some data's here my output right now

```
<!-- onclick="getinfo(this)"-->
<a href="#">Link1</a>Â Â Â
```

I wan't it to be

```
<a href="#">Link1</a>
```

Remove that Â and  from the script and I tried this code

```
foreach ($xpath->query('Â') as $link) {
  // Move all link tag content to its parent node just before it.
  while($link->hasChildNodes()) {
    $child = $link->removeChild($link->firstChild);
    $link->parentNode->insertBefore($child, $link);
  }
  // Remove the link tag.
  $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);
}
```

But it gives an error please help

Comment: Why don't you try *keeping* what you want, instead of *removing* what you don't?

Comment: I want to remove that contents

Comment: Yes, but sometimes the easiest way to remove something is to take everything **else**. Here, for example.

Comment: What is the example? I don't see it.